# C# WPF TabControl 動的に生成されるタブ毎に違うView（UserControl）を設定したい

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

開発環境は、Windows10、VS2022 .Net6(WPF) Prism(Unity) MVVM です。
（Prismはテンプレートパックにて導入しています）

TabControlの動的に生成される各タブに、それぞれに応じたViewを配置したいのですが、その方法が分かりません。

#### 前提として

- MainView に TabControl を配置
- 他、View(UserControl)として、AView,BView,CView,DView を作成
- AView には、「BView 追加」「CView 追加」「DView 追加」ボタンを配置
- BView,CView,DView はそれぞれ独立しており、配置しているコントロールはバラバラ
  （独立と書くと語弊あるかもしれませんが。他のViewとの関連は無いという意味です）

#### やりたいこと

- MainView の TabControl の最初のタブにAViewを配置
  （実行した最初はこの状態で。タブ1つのみ、AViewだけの状態です）
- MainView の TabControl のAView の各「追加」ボタンを押したら、押した順にタブを追加し、
  追加したタブには、該当するView（例えば、CView追加ボタンを押したら、追加されたタブにはCView）を配置
- 例えば。最初のAViewのみの状態から。DView追加→DView追加→BView追加としたら、
  2つ目、3つ目のタブはDView、4つ目のタブはBView としたい。
- 条件として、タブの数は毎回不定とする。

という事をしたいのですが、Viewが複数ある段階でどの様に実装すれば良いか分からず、途方に暮れてしまいました。

---

例えば、全てのタブが同じBViewのみだったらViewModelにて、

```
ObservableCollection<TabItemData> TabItems
```

の様にすれば出来るのは理解できたのですが、これが複数かつ、不定の場合にどうすれば良いのでしょうか。

一つの案として考えたのは、乱暴な方法なのですがAView～DViewまでのViewModelを1つにまとめたViewModelを実装し、それをObservableCollectionし、必要なプロパティだけ使用する、というものです。

もっとスマートな方法があると思い、ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授をお願い致したく、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こんな記事は関連してそうですか？ [\[WPF\] (MVVM)TabControl...](http://gacken.com/blog/program/wpf-86_20160821-2/), [\[WPF\] (MVVM)選択されている...](http://gacken.com/blog/program/wpf-79_20160821/), [WPF で画面遷移...](http://yujiro15.net/blog/index.php?id=148), [TabControlにMVVMで...](https://qiita.com/ietora/items/05960ae45c41874a2076), [Binding collection...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50351899/), [WPF MVVM: Binding...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26218766/), [How do I bind a TabControl...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5650812/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
一通り、目を通してみました。7つ目が有用と見ております。
（1つ目、2つ目、4つ目、5つ目は目を通し済みでしたが。私の理解不足か、フォーマットが同じ場合のViewで、全く違うViewでの実装の仕方が分かりませんでした。
また、3つ目はタブが固定なら有用と思いますが。どのタブにどのViewを配置するのか不定のため、この問題の解消には不向きかと思います。）
実装してみてから、また報告させていただきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabItemDataを継承した各クラスごとに[DataTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)を定義してはいかがでしょうか。

例えば以下のようなViewModelを用意します。
各ViewModelに[ObservableCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0)を追加する[ICommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=net-6.0)を持たせています。

```
public abstract class TabItemData : BindableBase
{
    public abstract string Header { get; set; } 
}

public class AViewModel : TabItemData
{
    public override string Header { get; set; } = "AView";
    public ICommand? CreateBView { get; set; }
    public ICommand? CreateCView { get; set; }
}

public class BViewModel : TabItemData
{
    public override string Header { get; set; } = "BView";
    public ICommand? CreateAView { get; set; }
    public ICommand? CreateCView { get; set; }
}

public class CViewModel : TabItemData
{
    public override string Header { get; set; } = "CView";
    public ICommand? CreateAView { get; set; }
    public ICommand? CreateBView { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MainViewModel() { CreateAViewModel(); }

    public ObservableCollection<TabItemData> TabItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TabItemData>();

    private void CreateAViewModel()
    {
        TabItems.Add(new AViewModel()
        {
            CreateBView = new DelegateCommand(CreateBViewModel),
            CreateCView = new DelegateCommand(CreateCViewModel),
        });
    }

    private void CreateBViewModel()
    {
        TabItems.Add(new BViewModel()
        {
            CreateAView = new DelegateCommand(CreateAViewModel),
            CreateCView = new DelegateCommand(CreateCViewModel),
        });
    }

    private void CreateCViewModel()
    {
        TabItems.Add(new CViewModel()
        {
            CreateAView = new DelegateCommand(CreateAViewModel),
            CreateBView = new DelegateCommand(CreateBViewModel),
        });
    }
}
```

これを[TabControl.ItemsSource](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)に設定し、各クラスの[DataTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)を用意してやれば、クラスに応じたViewを使用してくれるようになります。
※[UserControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)であるAView、BView、CViewの内容については省略します。[ICommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=net-6.0)を実行するボタンを配置しておけば良いです。

```
<Window 
    x:Class="Sample.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel}"    
    Title="MainView"
    Height="400" 
    Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AViewModel}">
            <local:AView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BViewModel}">
            <local:BView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CViewModel}">
            <local:CView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <d:Style.DataContext>
                <x:Type Type="local:TabItemData"/>
            </d:Style.DataContext>
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

型以外の条件で[DataTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)を切り替えたいのであれば、[TabControl.ItemTemplateSelector](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)に自作の[DataTemplateSelector](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)を設定してみてください。
例えばViewModelのプロパティの値によって[DataTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)を切り替えることも可能となります。

Comment: （すみません。諸事情でネットが出来ない環境でしたので見れませんでした）
ありがとうございます。
具体的なコードまで載せて頂き、大変に感謝しております。
参考にしながら、実装していこうと思います。
本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

Messenger パターンを使うという方法もあります。
ViewModel から View を操作したいときに使用するパターンで、メッセージダイアログを使いたいときによく利用されます。
Messenger パターンの詳細は MVVM Messenger あたりで検索すれば得られると思います。

タブを追加する機能は MainView(のコードビハインド)に実装し、 各 ViewModel から Messenger を介してタブ追加を MainView に要求するといった実装になるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
「Messenger パターン」について調べてみます。